# Changing the posts page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, navigation, selected, posts

The topic title might be a little misleading, but I didn't really know what title to give this question, but since it relates to changing the post page, I figured it would be fine.

So I actually figured out how to change the posts page and set up a static front page. Right now I have a landing page that is my front page and then a journal page, which is where my posts appear.

My issue is that when I click on a post the journal link in my navigation doesn't stay selected. And I would like users to know that when they click on a post they are still in the journal area by having the journal link in the navigation stay selected, but I can't figure out how to get the journal link to remain highlighted as the current link.

When a user goes to journal (the page that displays all of my posts) the journal link in the navigation stays selected. It's only when a user clicks on a post that journal is no longer selected.

*So I guess my question is:*
**How do I get the post page link to stay current/selected when on a post?**

I mean, I think I have an idea why it is not staying selected just by looking at the url's. When I'm on the journal page the url is (by the way I'm working locally which is why I can't link to the site):

`http://localhost/wordpress/journal/`

And when I'm on a post the url looks like this:

`http://localhost/wordpress/example-post/`

When really it should look like this:

`http://localhost/wordpress/journal/example-post/`

so that all the posts recognizes the journal as its parent, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Anyways, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!




**EDIT*
Turns out simply getting the url to be `http://localhost/wordpress/journal/example-post/` didn't work. Which tells me that there is something in the php that needs to be changed, added, and/or edited. So I started inspecting the journal link in the nav and it looks like on the posts page it is getting a few classes that it isn't getting on the post page.

Here is what the journal link looks like on the posts page:

`<li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-41 current_page_item current_page_parent menu-item-46"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/journal/">Journal</a></li>`

And here is what the journal link looks like on the post page:

`<li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current_page_parent menu-item-46"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/journal/">Journal</a></li>`

I compared the two and it looks like the journal link on the post page is missing a few classes that the journal link on the posts page has. Mainly `class="current-menu-item current_page_item"` which are classes that it would need to show up as selected/current (well, actually it only needs one of those classes to show up as selected/current). Anyways, I tried to find where those classes are being added in the php and it looks like they both appear `wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php`. The file looked quite complicated and I didn't want to mess with it and break the site, but anyone running Wordpress 3.5.1 should have the same file I have if you want to take a look at it. I'm guessing that is where the issue lies and am thinking I would need to add something in my themes functions to address the problem. I just don't know what that would be :/




**EDIT*

**Screenshot of the posts page**

*This is what the posts page looks like. Notice how JOURNAL is black while the other links are gray. I'm trying to get JOURNAL to stay black/selected/current when on a post*
[image: This is what the posts page looks like. Notice how JOURNAL is black while the other links are gray. I'm trying to get JOURNAL to stay black/selected/current when on a post]


**Screenshot of the post page**

*This is what the post page looks like. Notice how JOURNAL is not black/selected/current. Instead it is gray like all the other nav links. I'm trying to figure out how to get JOURNAL to stay black/selected/current when on both the post and/or the posts page. In other words when you are on the journal page or the journal entry page (journal page displays all journal entries, while journal entry page just displays the entry you are on).*
[image: This is what the post page looks like. Notice how JOURNAL is not black/selected/current. Instead it is gray like all the other nav links. I'm trying to figure out how to get JOURNAL to stay black/selected/current when on both the post and/or the posts page. In other words when you are on the journal page or the journal entry page (journal page displays all journal entries, while journal entry page just displays the entry you are on).]

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Go to settngs->Permalinks and select custom.  Add this: /journal/%postname%

I just tried this and it worked for me.  Hopefully it will work for you too!

-Lisa

Comment: Hi Lisa, thanks for the response! I tried your solution and it worked for adding journal to all the post's url, but unfortunately the journal link in my nav is still not staying selected/current. I thought that getting the url to show up as http://localhost/wordpress/journal/example-post/ would work, but no luck. I'm guessing there is something in the php that I have to change, edit, or add, but I'm not sure what or where that would be.

Comment: Btw, I'm using the bones starter theme to help me create my own theme. http://themble.com/bones/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say the journal link in your nav is not staying selected.

Comment: I added some screenshots to illustrate what is going on. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now.  I'm not sure how to do this myself, but I did find this article. It may be worth looking at http://www.vanseodesign.com/wordpress/hightlight-current-page-wordpress/ Sorry I couldn't be more help!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll look into it and see if I can figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the css  class in your stylesheet

ul li.current-menu-item { color:red;}

or other one

ul li.current-menu-item a { color:red;}

it will work for this

Comment: Hi Vickey. Thanks for your response, but unfortunately that doesn't resolve my problem. The issue doesn't have to do with defining the current-menu-item in the css. In fact, I already defined the current-menu-item, current_page_item, and even the current_page_ancestor, which is why the journal link is showing up selected as black on the posts page (because I set it to black). The issue really lies in getting the current-menu-item class to be assigned to the journal link on the post/journal entry page. I realized that the class is being assigned by to these links by `nav-menu-template.php`

Comment: However, I don't know how to edit the php to get it to assign the current-menu-item, current_page_item, or the current_page_ancestor class to the journal link on the post/journal entry page :(